# Multiple attributes in ng-style

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

I need to have multiple raw style attributes like :

```
$scope.css = "'width': 'calc(100% - "+$scope.fixedColumnsWidth+"'),'margin-left':'"+ $scope.fixedColumnsWidth+"'";

<div ng-style="{css}">
```

This is not working. It works when I use

```
<div style="{{css}}">
```

But not for IE.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ng-style waits for an object literal, so you need to adjust your code to

```
$scope.css = {
 width: 'calc(100% -'+$scope.fixedColumnsWidth+')',
 'margin-left': $scope.fixedColumnsWidth
}

<div ng-style="css"></div>
```

Answer (score 39):

Use below on view

```
<div ng-style="{
   'width': calc('100% -'+fixedColumnsWidth),
   'margin-left': fixedColumnsWidth}">
```