# Angular ng-style with a multiple conditional expression and multiple style attributes

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to add multiple style attribute for accordion group using `ng-style` with conditions as `ng-class` is not working with accordion.

Here is how i am trying:

```
ng-style="{ border: ivrMessageForm.ivr_messagetitle.$error.required && !isFormValid ? '2px solid' : 'none' }"
```

this is working fine. but want to add `border-color` too.

I tried this:

```
ng-style="{ border: ivrMessageForm.ivr_messagetitle.$error.required && !isFormValid ? '2px solid' : 'none', border-color: ivrMessageForm.ivr_messagetitle.$error.required && !isFormValid  ? 'red' : 'none'}"
```

but it gives me parse error.

i also tried this one but same parse error:

```
ng-style="ivrMessageForm.ivr_messagetitle.$error.required ? {border:'3px solid', border-color: 'red'} : {border:'none', border-color: 'none'}"
```

can anyone help me how to add multiple style attributes with multiple conditions using ng-style.

Comment: refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435883/multiple-attributes-in-ng-style

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add single quotes to 'border-color'

```
ng-style="{ border: ivrMessageForm.ivr_messagetitle.$error.required && !isFormValid ? '2px solid' : 'none', 'border-color': ivrMessageForm.ivr_messagetitle.$error.required && !isFormValid  ? 'red' : 'none'}"
```

Comment: single quote is necessary for all next attributes?

Comment: what about if i want to add same style on $error.pattern?

Comment: Depends on the attribute name. This is not a angularjs knowledge but javascript. If the property name contains more than one word,  you must  write it in hump format or or use quotation marks.That means you can also change 'border-color' to borderColor.

Comment: can you optimize this. Let suppose define style in js file as 

 $scope.css = {
        border: '3px solid',
        'border-color': 'red'
    }

How can i pass this css variable in ng-style with condition?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.styleobj = {};
  $scope.borderflag = true;
  $scope.widthflag = true;
  $scope.getStyle= function(){  
     if($scope.borderflag){
    $scope.styleobj.border = '2px solid';
     }if($scope.widthflag){
       $scope.styleobj.width = '100%';
        $scope.styleobj.font = 'italic bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif';
     }
     console.log($scope.styleobj);
     return $scope.styleobj;
  }
 
    $scope.name = 'Arindam Banerjee';
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
  <p ng-style="getStyle()">
   Hello, {{name}}!
  </p>
</div>
```

##