# Using angular variables in inline styles

Tags: angularjs

I want to use the background color from my json array, but this does not work.

```
<td ng-repeat="menus in $scope.menuList">
    <button class="head-button" style="background-color:{{menus.color}}" ui-sref="{{menus.link}}">
        <md-icon>{{menus.icon}}</md-icon>
        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">{{menus.tooltip}}</md-tooltip>
        <div class="head-mini-text">{{menus.text}}</div>
    </button>
</td>
```

How come that `style="background-color:{{menus.color}}"` is not working? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I conditionally apply CSS styles in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple attributes in ng-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435883/multiple-attributes-in-ng-style)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use angular directive `ng-style` to dynamically change the color of your background

**HTML**:

```
 <button class="head-button" ng-style="{'background-color':menus.color}" ui-sref="{{menus.link}}">
```

**For more reference**: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle